# Rollback last "git pull upstream" (conflict occurs) into the old state

Tags: git

I did update a file and committed the changes (`efe5e5d (HEAD, master) change about caption`), then fired `git pull upstream` while the upstream's code was changed recently, this of course caused me conflict.

#### `git show-ref`

```
efe5e5d65603419288e40b8e964aecba4626c99f refs/heads/master
879020dbcd1cf1f797577b66a9416c1007a1ad29 refs/remotes/upstream/HEAD
20e54d8ccaa4dba7890fa5db2e89394ab33a0c81 refs/remotes/upstream/dev
879020dbcd1cf1f797577b66a9416c1007a1ad29 refs/remotes/upstream/master
```

#### The conflicted file (index.html)

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
    <a href="about.html" class="btn btn-success">Goto About</a>
=======
    <a href="about.html" class="btn btn-success">About Page</a>
>>>>>>> 879020dbcd1cf1f797577b66a9416c1007a1ad29
```

#### `git status`

```
Your branch and 'upstream/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:   index.html
```

#### `git log`

```
* efe5e5d f72465f (HEAD, master) change about caption     
* f72465f 28645ce add link button                         
* 28645ce 48c2640 20e54d8 Merge branch dev'
```

**Question** How to rollback this last `git pull upstream` into the old state?

The purpose of this is to learn, it's not the real code. I think i cannot use `git reset`, I think the following are related.

1. `git update-ref refs/remotes/upstream/master refs/remotes/upstream/master@{1}`
2. `git checkout -- index.html` (I'm not sure because usually git status will suggest this)
3. What should I do with `refs/remotes/upstream/HEAD` ?

Please guide thanks.

#### Edited

I think I have found a solution for this problem.

1. `git merge --abort`
2. `git update-ref refs/remotes/upstream/master refs/remotes/upstream/master@{1}`

With these 2 commands, I then can fire `git pull upstream` again like this never happenned before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While doing a `git pull`, your tracking branch is updated and a merge is performed between your remote branch and local branch. If a conflict occurs, the merge stops in between allowing you to resolve them and then to `git commit`. Have a look at this:

```
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
```

The merge finishes after `git commit`. So, to return to a state where your branch was before `git pull upstream`, you'll have to do a hard reset since the changes are still unmerged.

```
git reset --hard
```

It will remove all the staged changes. To remove the conflicted files also(which are unstaged), do the following.

```
git add index.html
git reset --hard
```

Comment: `git reset --hard` also removes all tracked unstaged changes. Think twice before you use it

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I edited the file (index.html) and I already committed the changes (`efe5e5d (HEAD, master) change about caption`), so I made you guys misunderstood